# Knight's Tour - BackTracking in Java, Out of Bound

Tags: java, recursion, recursive-backtracking, knights-tour

I am trying to solve the problem where the problem states that, given a N * M chessboard, a Knight’s Tour is defined as the sequence of moves of a Knight, such that the Knight visits every square only once. Below is my code, however I am getting Array out of bound = 8, I know it comes when Moves tries to add value 2 in the present row with 6, however I am not sure how to get rid of it.

```
int MaxMove = 64; // for 8*8 chess Board
private int Moves[][] = new int[][] {{2, 1}, {2, -1}, {1, 2}, {1, -2}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, -2}};

void solveKnightTour(int[][] board)
{
    knightsTourUtil(board, 0, 0, 1);
}

private boolean isSafeMove(int[][] board, int r, int c)
{
    if(r < 0 && r > board.length-1 && c < 0 && c > board.length-1 &&  board[r][c] != -1)
        return false;
    return true;
}

private boolean knightsTourUtil(int[][] board, int presentRow, int presentCol, int KthMove)
{
    if (KthMove >= MaxMove)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Moves.length; i++)
    {
        int nextRow = presentRow + Moves[i][0];
        int nextCol = presentCol + Moves[i][1];
        if (isSafeMove(board, nextRow, nextCol))
        {
            board[nextRow][nextCol] = KthMove;
            if (knightsTourUtil(board, nextRow, nextCol, KthMove + 1)) 
                return true;
            else
                board[nextRow][nextCol] = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that `exception` because you tryed to access element with index which is out of bounds for your array.

This happens because `if` statement inside `isSafeMove` method isn't doing what you want it to do.

```
if(r < 0 && r > board.length-1 && c < 0 && c > board.length-1 &&  board[r][c] != -1)
```

You used `&&` so all those statements need to be `true` in other to execute `if` block, instead of `&&` you should use `||` in other to make it work if only 1 of those cases is true.

Like this:

```
if(r < 0 || r > board.length-1 || c < 0 || c > board.length-1 ||  board[r][c] != -1)
```

**EDIT**
At first I assumed that -1 is for not visited fields, but it turned out that -1 is for visited ones.
If should look like this:

```
if(r < 0 || r > board.length-1 || c < 0 || c > board.length-1 ||  board[r][c] == -1)
```

Comment: but in that case , if stamens returns false for is(safe, board, 2,1) when knight is at (0,0) even though it is a valid move.

Comment: Is -1 sign for already visited or not visited field?

Comment: initially all indices of the board are zero, while backtracking or removing the knight we place -1 on that spot so that next time we visit we know this is place is not occupied.(I also tried making spot 0 again but that just results in an infinite loop)

Comment: just change last if case to `board[r][c] == -1` and it should work.

Comment: Changed last statement to "==-1", now I am getting this output 00000000
00000000
01000000
00000000
002040620
00000000
000306300
00000000

Comment: If you are placing `-1` when field is visited, and `0` is starting value, then that if case should work, you shouldn't reset spot to 0 again, leave it as -1, its impossible to get 2/3/4 or any other number unless you are putting it in array somewhere else.